# Generating random rectangles with collison

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in which there is a gun on the far left side of the screen, that has a fixed `x` coordinate, and the `y` moves based off of the mouse position. A bird is at the top of the screen, and the objective is to not have objects hit the bird.

Example code:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
displaySurf = pygame.display.set_mode((460, 720))
obstacleChoice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = 0 # (Hoping to use this to scroll the screeen (see line 24))
fps = pygame.time.Clock()
gun = pygame.image.load('gun.png')
bird = pygame.image.load('goose.png')
ammo = pygame.image.load('ammo.png')
sky = pygame.image.load('sky.png')
stone = pygame.image.load('stone.png')
lvlOne = pygame.image.load('lvlOne.png')
BLACK = (0,0,0)
grey = pygame.Color('grey')
x = 100 # bullets start
loop = False
font = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 24)
bullets = 12 # start with 12 bullets
score = 0 # score starts at 0

while True:

    y -= 1
    score += 0.06 # increase the score as time goes on
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mousePressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if mousePressed[0] and bullets > 0: # if clicked, and player has bullets
        loop = True # allows for the bullet to fly across the screen when clicked, rather than only move while clicked
    if loop == True:
        if x < 460: # if the bullet hasn't left the screen
            x += 20 
    if x >= 460: # if the bullet has left the screen
        x = 100 # put the bullet back to the barrel of gun
        loop = False # stop movig the bullet
        bullets -= 1 # Take away a bullet 

    displaySurf.blit(sky, (0, y)) # sky
    displaySurf.blit(bird, (200, 10)) # Bird image
    pygame.Rect(x - 8, mousePos[1] + 5, 8, 4) # collison rect for bullet
    pygame.draw.rect(displaySurf, BLACK, (x - 8, mousePos[1] + 5, 8, 4)) # image rect for bullet
    displaySurf.blit(gun, (1, mousePos[1])) # gun image
    bulletSurface = font.render('bullets:{0}'.format(bullets), False, (0, 0, 0)) #bullet number
    displaySurf.blit(bulletSurface, (370, 0)) # bullets number display
    scoreSurface = font.render('score:{0}'.format(int(score)), False, (0, 0, 0)) # score 
    displaySurf.blit(scoreSurface, (370, 15)) # score display
    pygame.display.flip() # update
    fps.tick(60) # frames
```

How can i:

1. Generate random rectangles that if collide with a bullet are
   destroyed, and if collided with the bird the game ends.
2. Scroll the screen so that the  objects fly towards the bird.

Comment: Nice of you to tell us about your project - but what do you think to accomplish here? Create your rectangles and if problems arise, ask specific questions. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question.

Comment: my question is how to make random rectangles and scroll the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make random rectangles, simply use python's random module. I'll include a class for it as well.

```
import random

class Enemy:

    def __init__(self): 
        self.x = random.randint(0, 460)  #460 is the x resolution
        self.y = 720   I assume these rectangles start at the bottom of the screen.

    def move(self, speed):
        self.y += speed
        # Moves them up the screen, towards the bird.

    def draw(self, display):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 20, 20)
    # Not sure what color, so I set it to black. Not sure what size, so I set it to 20
```

This is just a basic class, and I'm sure you'll probably have to add more (like using the enemy's `Rect` for collision and adding collision methods), but tell me if it helps.